# Javascript: Clicking Link to Download pdf

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a JS program which should open a webpage www.mysite.com & click on a link inside that webpage to download a pdf.
The link to click looks like this:

```
<a onclick="download();return false;" href="#noWhere">Click to Download</a>
```

Ordinarily, manually clicking the link, calls the following function to download the pdf:

```
function download() {
    document.forms[0].action = path + "/xxW04_sv_0140Action.do";
    document.forms[0].target = "_self";
    document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

My code is simplified javascript code to open the page & click on the "Click to Download" button is this:

```
<script>

var linkname = "http://www.mysite.com";

var windowname = "window_1"

// Opens a new window
var myWindow = window.open(linkname, windowname ,"width=400,height=600");    

//should open a link to download pdf
myWindow.document.getElementById('href = \"#noWhere\"').click();

</script>
```

So far I can open the webpage "mysite.com" in a seperate window using but for some reason no button clicking is happening and certainly no pdf is downloaded.
Of course if I manually click the "Click to Download" button it downloads.

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong? Why I cannot simulate a click with the above js code?

Or possibly give me some things to try. Any help much appreciated and Than you.

**UPDATE:**
From the initial answers below, possibly this method is doomed for failure! Can anyone suggest a better way I could be downloading these pdfs?

Comment: You can't click on sites using javascript if they are not in the same domain as your script. Why can't you just copy the url of .pdf to your script?

Comment: getElementById('href = \"#noWhere\"') won't work. The string you pass to this method is not an id. You should use querySelectorAll

Comment: @kamilkp, I thought getElementById('href = \"#noWhere\"') may be a long shot but thre is no id as such on the link. Do you see any other way to identify this link? How would I use "querySelectorAll" ?

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('[href="#noWhere"]')

Answer (score 2):

You'd better use:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/mypdf.pdf">
```

This should download that pdf file.

Comment: I would love to use use the file's path, @Karlo Sintic, like above but i dont know it. The pdf's are freely downloadable from a website but because there are so many every week, I'ld like to automate the download process. Is there anyway I can find out the pdf's path? As I have said, normally I just click on that href which seems to run

Answer (score 0):

It won't work. The [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) will prevent you from accessing the content of any pages loaded from another domain.

Also, as [@kamilkp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2137653/kamilkp) pointed out, you have to provide the `getElementById()` function with an id value. You can't just plug any old stuff in there and expect it to work.

Another problem is your reliance on clicks for this to work. What about users that use the tab key to select links and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to follow the link?

Comment: Thanks for letting me now about the "same origin policy" Adassko & @Squeamish. if i cant use JS,  can i use some other scripting language?